# When I SSH into my EC2 instance, how do I figure out what server it is currently running?

Tags: node.js, apache, amazon-web-services, nginx, server

When I ssh into the EC2 instance and look around the server configuration files, I see Apache config files, NGINX config files. Why are both servers there? Which one takes priority? Do both servers run simultaneously? Do they work together? Where would my server side code go for Node.js?

It is Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux/4.10.2 on an Elastic Beanstalk environment.

Comment: NodeJs don't use apache or nginx,  it's create its own server

Comment: This is in the AWS EC2 instance. It seems it is using Nginx as its route handler.

Comment: We're going to need more information than what has been supplied. What have you installed on it? What base image did you chose when you made it? What are you trying to do with the server?

Comment: I edited my description to add more information.

Comment: @virendernehra It's very common to use a server like Nginx or Apache to proxy to Node.js.

Comment: @V.Villacis A bit of a tip for Beanstalk... don't mess with the environment if you can help it.  There is a lot of stuff Amazon has set up on there and it can all unpredictably change.  Ideally, you should never have to SSH into the EC2 instances for your Beanstalk environment at all.  (Although of course it can be helpful when figuring out what is going wrong.)

Answer (score 2):

To quote the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.container.html):

> The AWS Elastic Beanstalk Node.js platform is a platform version for
>   Node.js web applications that can run behind an nginx proxy server,
>   behind an Apache server, or standalone.

I would assume that to simplify deployment, Elastic Beanstalk chooses to deploy both NGINX and Apache, regardless of which mechanism you choose to serve content.

The [configuration options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html#command-options-nodejs) are `ProxyServer=apache/nginx/none`.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question in Serverfault and got this answer. You can run the command `ps ax | grep -E '(apache2|httpd|nginx)'` to see which one is running.